# jquery mouse move capture inaccuracy

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm facing an strange problem.
I capture the mouse movements with:

```
var mmoves = [];
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(event) {
   mmoves.push({x:event.pageX, y:event.pageY})
}
```

Then I attach a div to the page like:

```
$("body").append('<div id="mouseemul" style="padding:0; margin:0; color: red; background-color: blue; width: 1px; height: 1px;">*</div>');
```

and then try to playback the moves

It works ok on most pages but on some pages the playback starts ("*" initial position) some pixels to the right (x). The y is ok but the x is about 120px to the right. On other pages it is accurate. On the not accurate pages, when the mouse goes close the right scrollbar it goes beyond the right page border and produces a horizontal scrollbar.

I think this has to do with some css styling of the page being playback.

Does anybody has an idea what may be causing this ?
How could I get the actual offset (in case there is an offset for such pages) ?

Thanks a lot,

Hernan

--Edited--
It is obvious that the x displacement is due to the positioning of the main document. The first element gives a $.position() of 0,134 and if I SUBSTRACT that amount from the recorded data the playback is accurate. The problem is that this displacement does not happen in every page and I dont know how to figure out when the displacement occurs and when not (to correct it by substracting).

Comment: How are you positioning those divs?  I see nothing in that code to put it in the right position.

Comment: What about `clientX`/`clientY`?

Comment: The divs are positioned via $("#div").css({top: yy, left: xx}). The yy and xx are the pageX and pageY collected from the mousemove.

Comment: I tried clientX and clientY but the effect is the same.
It appears that on "some" pages either the pageX,pageY are "moved" some pixels to the right (some pixels = the position of the first element of the body) or the playback (positioning of the "*" div) is displaced to the right x pixels.

Comment: My main concern is finding a way to know when such displacement will occur during playback (or recording of the mouse movements).

Comment: Do yourself a favor: jsfiddle !

Comment: Is it just an issue with the variable window sizes?  Try making the coordinates relative to a known element, instead of relative to the page or the client.

Comment: P.S. this was question was posted 18 months ago.  If you found a solution please add it below for the community's sake.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the `html/body` being "*normalized*". Try running something like a nomalizing css script on every page, bet it fixes the issue, however, you'll probably have to fix other issues with other elements. In simple, some pages in some browsers render body or html tag as having padding and therefor the doc position is thrown off. You can find a good normal script [***HERE***](http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css), if that is the answer, lemme know and i'll post as one with much more info.

Comment: is the div in absolute position? is the div placed at top;0;left:0?

Answer (score 1):

### Recording

If you want to capture and replay mouse movement you can try "recording" from the `document`.
This would use the x and y chords from the window.

To do this you can use the document DOM element:

```
var m = [];

// Using the document instead of body might solve your issue
$( document ).mousemove(function( e ){

  m.push({ x : e.pageX, y : e.pageY });

});
```

### Replaying

#### HTML/CSS

Your HTML/CSS should be a div on the page set with `position: fixed` which should match your javascript chord samples as `fixed` is absolutely positioned to the window:

```
<style>
    .replay {
        /* Use position fixed to match window chords */
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

        /* These are just for show */
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: red;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
    }
</style>

<div class="replay"></div>
```

#### Javascript

To replay your captured chords you can use something like this:

```
var $replay = $('.replay'), // Get mouse simulator
    i = 0, l = m.length,
    pos, t;

// Recursive animation function
function anim(){

  // Cache current position
  pos = m[i];

  // Move to next position
  $replay.css({ top: pos.y, left: pos.x });

  i++;

  // Exit recursive loop
  if ( i === l )
     clearTimeout( t );
  // Or keep going
  else
    t = setTimeout(anim, 100); // Timeout speed controls animation speed

}

// Start animation loop
anim();
```

### Demo

Try it out on this <kbd>[demo](http://jsbin.com/ocufic/8/)</kbd>.